# Разделение жесткого диска

Tags: ubuntu

У меня стоял linux ubuntu и windows(сейчас не работает), я могу отформатировать чать диска выделенную под винду и прибавить эту память к линуксу?[image: сейчас разделение на дисках выглядит так]

Comment: Можно. После операции "ресайза" появится неразмеченное место (unallocated). Не знаю как объяснить, но его нельзя будет просто так прилепить к sda5 (если не ошибаюсь). На неразмеченном месте можно создать еще один диск. Либо использовать [LVM](https://losst.ru/sozdanie-i-nastrojka-lvm-linux)

Comment: Форматировать удаляемый раздел вовсе необязательно. Ты хочешь sda5 присоединить к sda6?

Comment: @TotalPusher, идущие подряд разделы вполне можно объединить. Меня смущает только что первый из объединяемых разделов является системным и он пытается что-то делать из этой самой системы.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, тут три виндовых раздела. sda2 и sda3 можно просто удалить и создать на их месте нужное количество разделов, которые затем смонтировать в, например, /var, /home и/или /usr, перенеся данные со старого места. То же самое и с sda5 с той лишь разницей, что его ни с чем слепить не получится, только поделить, если нужно. Ну или да, LVM на все три этих раздела, а на нём уже тома́ по вкусу и потребностям.

Answer (score 3):

Да это возможно. Но сомневаюсь, что это можно сделать с помощью тулзы, что на скрине.
Я бы посоветовал что-то типа EASEUS Partition Master.
Грузиться мимо текущей операционки.
Ну и бекап. Операция экстремально рискованная.

Comment: GParted тоже должен уметь. Но вот попытка это делать из системы, находящейся на изменяемом разделе меня тоже смущает.

Answer (score 3):

Вы желаете освободить /dev/sda5 и присоединить освободившееся место к /dev/sda6? Это возможно, если они занимают смежные участки на диске. И менно с помощью GParted.

Есть только одна проблема - если мы что-то делаем с разделом диска, то этот раздел должен быть **отмонтирован** ! Поэтому, последовательность действий такова:

1. Грузимся с любого лайве-CD
2. Запускаем gparted
3. В выпадающем списке дисков (правый верхний угол окна программы) выбираем нужный диск
4. Удаляем в нём виндовозный раздел
5. Для раздела с линукс делаем ресайз. gparted подскажет Вам новый размер.
6. В меню "Файл" говорим "Выйти"
7. gparted спросит: "Выполнить изменения?".
8. Сделать расслабленный выдох и нажать кнопку "Да".